# Magento 2: How to show New Products in a particular Category?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, category, xml, admin-panel

I have a category named **NEW** and I want to show all new products in this category (filter by  Set Product as New From To attribute), how can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show anything that you've tried?

Comment: I have copy list.phtml file then rename it then call it on new category then try to fetch like $todayDate  = date('Y-m-d', time());
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate));

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new static block from admin.
2. Insert widget in a static block.
3. Select **Catalog New Products List** in widget type.

**OR** you can simply paste below code in your static block content

```
<p>{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="all_products" products_count="10" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}</p>
```

4. Go to your **New** category > Display mode and set **Static block only**.
5. Go to your **New** category > Content and Add CMS Block which we have created in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the answer is older, I am currently facing the same problem.
However, I do not want to display the products as a block but normally in the layered navigation.